# Conditionally Formatting Rows in VBA dynamically colours the cells incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I recorded a macro to conditionally format some rows in excel using vba, but when I try to run it a second time, or when I try looping it for a dynamic selection of range, it paints the cells the wrong colour and in the wrong direction.  I want the cells to be painted from red to white, high to low, but the code paints the cells orange to white, low to high. Here is my code:

```
Sub ConForm()

Sheets("Percentage").Activate

Dim lastRow, currRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range


lastRow = Sheets("Percentage").Range("B250").End(xlUp).Row
currRow = 9

For currRow = 9 To (lastRow - 1)
    'Range("F" & currRow & ":AL" & currRow).Select

    Set rng = Sheets("Percentage").Range("F9:AL9") '"rng_ConForm" & currRow)
    rng.Select

    rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope

Next currRow
End Sub
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks

Edit: Here is the data after running. Before being run for the first time, all conditional formatting is cleared

**A) After running once**

[image]

**B) After running twice**

[image]

Comment: just tested and it works for me

Comment: the data is in a pivot table, would this effect anything?

Comment: should not. can you post a screenshot of your data and your results after the code is run?